# Can I use transferwise business instead of a traditional bank account for my business?

Tags: united-states, limited-liability-company, european-union

I have a transferwise business account and it provides me with the banking information I need to receive electronic payments from my customers (routing, number, IBAN etc...). Can this be my "business bank account" and from there to add myself as a new recipient and take owner draws or even link digital wallets for business expenses?

Comment: @Fattie Tnx for suggestion. I called them and they said you can use the account as a business bank account and many of their customers use it for that purpose. Perhaps you're referring to a personal account? They have a business line which I was referring to.

Comment: Fantastic news / maybe there has been a change.  You could actually put in an answer based on that great info.  You're quite sure you can **use it as a bank account, storing money there** (not just "for business use" ?)

Comment: Will report here once everything is verified. They sent a written message confirming, but one never knows. They also said certain rules must be followed or they'll block the account, but then any business person must follow similar rules anyways.

Comment: Thanks much for your info.  Let's see how it goes!  :)